# Добавление нескольких полей на страницу не перезагружая ее, и отправка данных в БД.

Tags: php, sql

Добавляемые через JS поля на страницу. Каждое новое поле должно иметь уникальное имя. Их необходимо встраиваться в sql запрос для отправки в БД, но количество полей изначально не известно.

Comment: @addon Вы ужа задали подобный вопрос, не повторяйте вопросов, это не увеличит качество ответа на него! Не думайте что ХэшКод слишком кишит знатоками которые готовы Вам дать моментальный ответ! Знтоками он конечно кишит, но наличием знатоков в тот момент в который вам нужно получить отевт, не гарантирует моментального ответа! По этому соблюдайте трпение!

Comment: вопрос чуть изменился. впредь буду думать, а потом писать вопрос. извиите

Comment: Вы имеете право изменть свой вопрос указав в нем **UPD** Далее сам вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Простой скрипт, добавляющий поля на страницу:

```
<script>
function dupl(x){
    x = x.parentNode;
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(x.cloneNode(true), x);
}
</script>
<div><input type="text" name="fupload[]" /><span onclick="dupl(this)">+</span></div>
```

Дальше сам попробуй ну или ктонить может поможет, не хочу мучиться)

Comment: вот добавление я сделал, а как сделать sql-запрос чтоб в нем указывались все поля? И скажите зачем в имени скобки "name="fupload[]""?

Comment: @addon при отправке будет создан массив.

Comment: каждое поле будет называться fupload (1-2-3-4 и тд). Реально лучше создай ограничение. К примеру 15 полей максимум и в базе тоже создай 15 полей и заноси туда информацию. Если можешь поподробнее опиши ситуацию.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку на странице добавляется список(select) и поле(text). В select значение у элементов  каждого свое. У поля text пишем имя с квадр.скобками (в неё будут записываться значения всех добавленных полей на страницу в виде массива).
Получается вот так:

 1. список engr - выбираем "мука"

    поле ves[] - 100

 2. список engr - выбираем "сахар"

    поле ves[] - 50
 
 3. список engr - выбрать "соль"

    поле ves[] - 60
и т.д.

Потом их нужно отправить в БД через sql